# One word equivalent to "play with someone's hair"

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

In the sentence:
Her head was in his lap, and he was **playing** with her **hair**.

Given that what the verb really defines is him brushing her hair with his hand or stroking it gently, is there a *better way* to express that ?

Comment: Of course there is. Hair-toying.

Comment: Is he brushing and/or touching the woman's hair?

Comment: Both actually .

Comment: This question about translating "[cafuné](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/cafun%C3%A9)" to english is related: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4777/como-traduzir-cafun%c3%a9-para-o-ingl%c3%aas (in Portuguese)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use one word to say "play with someone's hair", but I think the verb "to caress" does a better job of expressing the idea of him lovingly stroking her hair:

> *Her head was in his lap, and he was **caressing her hair**.*

Definition:

> caress: to touch someone gently in a way that shows you love them

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/caress_1))

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know how I missed this !

Comment: You are welcome, Ragheb. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 6):

Consider, ***fondle***.

> : to handle, stroke or touch lovingly [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fondle)

Answer (score 0):

The word cafuné in Brazilian Portuguese is literally "the act of fondling someone's hair". It's considered untranslatable to English, thus could be a loanword or borrowed word.

Answer (score -1):

To "tousle someone's hair" is to play with someone's hair...

Comment: Nice idea!  BUT, the OED defines tousle as "*To pull about roughly; to handle (esp. a woman) rudely or indelicately; to disorder, dishevel (the hair, clothes, etc.)*'

Comment: This is probably why the definition of "play" was explicitly stated in the question, although you can try this way until she is no longer receiving messages from you.