# To *play* with somebody's hair -- replacement for "play"

Tags: phrases, synonyms, vocabulary

I've came across the topic about equivalent to phrase "play with sb's hair" in which people suggested some fancy words. 
[One word equivalent to "play with someone's hair"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285964/one-word-equivalent-to-play-with-someones-hair#comment637487_285964)

I'm wondering whether is it correct to say "toy with sb's hair", for instance:
- I like toying with girls' hair, would you mind?

Comment: would who mind?! We aren't *the* English language here, you can Do What You Like™! It all depends on the context - where will you be writing it?

Comment: @marcellothearcane -  I read that as being part of the example sentence.  I.e.  Walk up to a girl, announce your fetish and ask if they would let you indulge.  Perfectly fine English.  Creepy behavior.

Comment: @Jim, In that case, I don't mind at all, so long as you're not going to progress to *my* hair! Maybe 'I like fetishising girls' hair, would you mind?' is better?

Comment: Krzesimir, what exactly are you asking that isn't answered in the question that you linked?

Comment: @marcellothearcane - No. You can’t use “fetish” like that.

Comment: @Jim [who says?](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fetishising) - you knew exactly what I meant...

Comment: @Jim, it's the BrE spelling of [_fetishize_](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fetishize?s=t).

Comment: Vanderpn, I asked if it is right to use *toy* instead of *play*, nobody touched that in the topic. To you guys, I used to interact like that with friends in class when I attended school and this is the reason why I've come up with mentioned sentence :P

Comment: 'I've came up' I mean, sorry :)

Comment: @marcellothearcane - I knew what you meant because of context. I was using fetish to mean an abnormal sexual attraction to a non-sexual body part. I would take your conjugation to mean “to make a fetish of something” in that sense it must refer to the religious magical item. So - “can I make a fetish out of your hair?”  which doesn’t mean the same thing at all as, “can I toy with or fondle your hair”

Comment: @Jim oh, fair enough! Number 3 has [your meaning](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fetish), which was linked from fetishise. I can see where the issue arises though.

Comment: @Krzesimir, you had it right the first time: "I've _come_ up with"

Comment: Lol, you're right, using a smartphone makes me think too fast. Thanks for notice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The toy/play swap is perfectly acceptable.** Play [is a synonym of toy](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/toy), especially in a (potentially) flirtatious way.

With English, there is rarely **a** 'correct' word, most are interchangeable. It all depends on what you want to mean, and how your speech will be interpreted. If you're ever unsure, check a thesaurus, and then a dictionary (to make sure the meanings are the same)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! :) Also, as my English becomes more fluent, I get the feeling when and how to change words to express the meaning in my own way, but in this case I just was unsure :) Thanks once again!